# How to get datetime group by days via LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable which contains the data of whole month. Now i want to get those data group by days via linq. I already have this query but i need a little change. My day starts from 7 O Clock & ends at next day 7 O Clock. My current query is :

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new
    {
        day = row.Field<DateTime>("dateandTime"),
        Code = row.Field<string>("Code"),
        Name = row.Field<string>("Name")
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        day = g.Key.day,
        Code = g.Key.Code,
        quantity = g.Count()
    }
        );
```

`dateandtime` formate is : 2014-01-02 05:26:10.567

How can i get the data from the datatable group by days of the whole month ?

I want the data from 7 to 7. If the month ends, then last date data should also get the data of next date upto 7 O Clock.

Comment: "dateandtime formate is : 2014-01-02 05:26:10.567" - no it's not, it's a `DateTime`...

Comment: `dateandtime` is the variable name.

Comment: Well it's the field name in the row, apparently. But if it's genuinely a `DateTime` field, then it doesn't have a format - each value is just a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just group by the `Day` property of the `DateTime` value, after adjusting the date/time accordingly by 7 hours. Of course, if you actually have multiple months/years involved, that will give you somewhat odd results, but...

```
.GroupBy(row => new
{
    Day = row.Field<DateTime>("dateandTime").AddHours(-7).Day,
    Code = row.Field<string>("Code"),
    Name = row.Field<string>("Name")
})
```

(Note: you'll need to make sure that your original query to find the data for a month takes the 7 hour shift into account. Also, if this 7 hour shift is actually due to time zones, there are probably better options.)

Comment: I said My day starts from 7 O Clock & ends at next day 7 O Clock. Above query giving data of 12 to 12.

Comment: @bogojane: Ah, I missed that bit. Easy to fix though - editing.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet, it is exactly what i wanted. It it possible for group by month also, if i have the data of whole year. Condition is same i.e. 7 to 7.

Comment: @bogojane: Just do the same for `Month` as another property in the grouping: `Month = row.Field<DateTime>("dateandTime").AddHours(-7).Month`